# Create SharePoint Choice Fields with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, choicefield

I want to be able to create a list and choice column with PowerShell but the Choice column always fails. I have found a few examples showing my code to work so I must be missing something.

[MSDN Link to Add field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477246.aspx)

```
clear
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

function CreateCustomList($siteCollectionUrl, $listName, $listTitle, $listDescription) {
    $spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $siteCollectionUrl  
    $spTemplate = $spWeb.ListTemplates["Custom List"]  
    $spListCollection = $spWeb.Lists  
    $spListCollection.Add($listName, $listDescription, $spTemplate)  
    $path = $spWeb.url.trim()

    #set display name
    $spList = $spWeb.GetList("$path/Lists/$listName")
    $spList.Title = $listTitle
    $spList.Update()

    return $spList
}  

function AddChoiceField($spList, $title){
    #create choices collection
    $choices = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
    $choices.Add("Completed") | Out-Null
    $choices.Add("Pending") | Out-Null
    $choices.Add("Not Applicable") | Out-Null

    #create choice field
    $name = $title -replace '\s',''
    $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Choice
    $name = $spList.Fields.Add($name, 
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Choice, 
        $false, 
        $false, 
        $choices);

    #Set display Name
    $spCol = $spList.Fields[$name]
    $spCol.Title = $title
    $spCol.Update()
}

$siteCollectionUrl = "http://URL"  
$listName = "CustomCheckList"
$listTitle = "Custom Checklist"
$listDescription = "This checklist is used because of reasons"

$spList = CreateCustomList $siteCollectionUrl $listName $listTitle $listDescription
AddChoiceField $spList, "First checklist item"
```

Edit:
Here is the error message returned

```
Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "5".
At line:11 char:5
+     $name = $spList.Fields.Add($name,
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Exception setting "Title": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:19 char:5
+     $spCol.Title = $title
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Comment: Add fieldAsXml instead of writtting this much code.

Comment: "My pile of code doesn't work: *splat*" isn't a good question. Fails how? What should it do, what does it do? What errors does it give? What have you tried doing to isolate the problem lines of code, or to fix it?

Comment: My bad I forgot to add the error details.

Comment: @Vaibhav I plan on creating multiple lists and each one will have a lot of choice fields with the same values. This is why I wanted reusable functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a case of not understanding how PowerShell handled parameters and return values.

When calling functions and passing in parameters, if you do not use the parameter name it assumes your passing in an array to the first parameter of the function. This is why Thriggle's suggestion of using AddFieldAsXml did not exist and failed for me.

For return values, all outputs from the function are passed back as an array. I used $return[-1] to grab the last parameter from the return value and save that as the list object that I wanted.

```
$return = CreateCustomList $siteCollectionUrl $listName $listTitle $listDescription
$spList = $return[-1]
AddChoiceField -spList $spList -title "SR Test List"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct, so there must be something else going wrong.

In PowerShell, `AddFieldAsXml()` does tend to be a little easier if you're willing to play with strings of XML.

Since it only has one parameter (and it's a string) PowerShell is less likely to get confused with various object/parameter types and potential or imaginary method overloads.

```
function AddChoiceField($spList, $title){
    $name = $title -replace '\s',''
    $xml = '<Field Required="FALSE" Description="" DisplayName="' + $name + 
        '" Type="Choice" Format="Dropdown" FillInChoice="FALSE">' +
        '<CHOICES><CHOICE>Completed</CHOICE><CHOICE>Pending</CHOICE><CHOICE>Not Applicable</CHOICE></CHOICES>' +
        '</Field>'
    $spList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($xml);
    $spList.Update();
    $spCol = $spList.Fields[$name]
    $spCol.Title = $title
    $spCol.Update()
}
```

Comment: This would potentially be a workaround but what is wrong with my code. I have found a few examples of others doing the same thing. http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2013/06/how-to-create-list-using-power-shell.html#.Upem3cROMnU

Comment: I just tested this and it failed "Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField] does not contain a method named 'AddFieldAsXml' "

Comment: @SamNesbitt That's very curious. `$spList.Fields` should be of type SPFieldCollection, not SPField. Maybe you need to do a little investigation into the `$spList` parameter value and make sure it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: @SamNesbitt What do you see when you execute `$spList.Fields.GetType()`?

Comment: You helped me figure out the issue. It was returning an array instead for the list object. I was also passing parameters into the methods wrong.